# Identify row in a matrix corresponding to a vector

Tags: r, matrix

Assume a matrix that contains all bit strings of length `r` and is in order.

```
library(gtools)
mat<-permutations(n = 2, r = 5, v = c(0,1), repeats.allowed = TRUE)
mat<-cbind(mat, round(runif(nrow(mat)), digits = 2))
```

and several vectors each with `r` elements:

```
r=5
vec<-t(replicate(100,sample(c(0,1),5,replace=T)))
```

For each vector (i.e, row in `vec`) I would like to identify the corresponding row in `mat`

Note: I would like to list the result for each row, not just the `unique` elements.

Is there an efficient way to do this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
indx1 <- do.call(`paste0`,as.data.frame(mat[,-6]))
indx2 <- do.call(`paste0`, as.data.frame(vec))
sapply(indx2, function(x) mat[indx1 %in% x,6])
```

Comment: this is almost good for my purpose. the only thing is that I would need to know the value of the last column in 'mat' for each row of 'vec'. in the current setup I cannot get this information for each row in 'vec' because it only lists the unique elements in mat

Comment: so basically the output should be in the order of the vectors in 'vec'. The first row of the output should correspond to the first row of 'vec' and so on.

Comment: yes I understand but is there a way to have it not for unique but for all rows in corresponding order?